# Expressjs REST API explorer

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I've been playing with loopback and it has very nice API Explorer (somehow reminds me Java's JMX),
apparently it is integrated inside the framework itself.

Is there a simple way to recreate the same experience with any of the npm packages?
If not, how do you expose your API to clients side devs in a convenient way except a google doc?

[image]

Comment: Good documentation in your source code repo? OR just docs on your site.

Comment: It will be very hard to automatically(!) recreate such an interface if you are only using express. Frameworks will not know anything about your application structure. Loopback automatizes it by using Models. Your best bet will be writing something yourself.

Comment: Wow, I gotta say, I love that single colour-coded view. I wrote and use booster https://github.com/deitch/booster to build my apps, since it handlers all of the messy controller, models, validations, cascading, etc. etc. my server.js incredibly clean. I definitely could see building that kind of view for booster apps.

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui

Answer (score 5):

A bit late to the party, but that's what [Swagger](http://swagger.io/) is for.

[Swagger-tools](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-tools) is particularly popular for Node.js and I can vouch for it!

Comment: Replying to a Stack Overflow question is never late. It's a top hit on Google and it really helps me out - thanks !

Comment: not just what swagger is for, loopback uses swagger: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-swagger

Answer (score 0):

You can use expressjs-api-explorer from [here](https://github.com/samundrak/expressjs-api-explorer#readme)

But I guess you have to register all your routes into your root (app.js or server.js or similar) file.I have registered my routes into the separate module (eg. post.routes.js , users.routes.js) and in my app.js I have only one route for 'server:port/' i.e. app.get('/' ,handler) and  expressjs-api-explorer returns only that one on the UI :

[image]

You need to also install "jade" as a dependency. Hope this helps.Cheers!